# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'voice' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

So I'm trying to make a command to play music in a vc, but here's my problem whenever I run the command it gives me this error `(node:11) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'voice' of undefined` whenever I try to do anything with this command it doesn't work. It just gives me that error over and over and over again. I haven't found any fix to this yet but I'll keep looking. If any of you find out how to fix this please answer my post.

**code:**

````
const { Util, voice, Client } = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Client();

module.exports.run = async(message, args) => {
const channel = message.member.voice.channel.join
    if (!channel) return message.channel.send('I\'m sorry but you need to be in a voice channel to play music!');
    const permissions = channel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('I cannot connect to your voice channel, make sure I have the proper permissions!');
    if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('I cannot speak in this voice channel, make sure I have the proper permissions!');

    const serverQueue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
    const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[0].replace(/<(.+)>/g, '$1'));
    const song = {
        id: songInfo.videoDetails.video_id,
        title: Util.escapeMarkdown(songInfo.videoDetails.title),
        url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url
    };

    if (serverQueue) {
        serverQueue.songs.push(song);
        console.log(serverQueue.songs);
        return message.channel.send(`✅ **${song.title}** has been added to the queue!`);
    }

    const queueConstruct = {
        textChannel: message.channel,
        voiceChannel: channel,
        connection: null,
        songs: [],
        volume: 2,
        playing: true
    };
    message.client.queue.set(message.guild.id, queueConstruct);
    queueConstruct.songs.push(song);

    const play = async song => {
        const queue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
        if (!song) {
            queue.voiceChannel.leave();
            message.client.queue.delete(message.guild.id);
            return;
        }

        const dispatcher = queue.connection.play(ytdl(song.url))
            .on('finish', () => {
                queue.songs.shift();
                play(queue.songs[0]);
            })
            .on('error', error => console.error(error));
        dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(queue.volume / 5);
        queue.textChannel.send(` Start playing: **${song.title}**`);
    };

    try {
        const connection = await channel.join();
        queueConstruct.connection = connection;
        play(queueConstruct.songs[0]);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`I could not join the voice channel: ${error}`);
        message.client.queue.delete(message.guild.id);
        await channel.leave();
        return message.channel.send(`I could not join the voice channel: ${error}`);
    }
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "play",
    aliases: []
}```
````

Comment: What does the `message` variable contain?

Answer (score 0):

```
const channel = message.member.voice.channel.join
```

does not exist...

Try using:

```
const channel = message.member.voice.channel
```

It checks if the user is in any voice channel.
If it does not work then your message.member returns undefined. Try logging message.member to se if it actually returns undefined and find out why since that part of code should work fine.